# Обновление результата запроса в DBEdit

Tags: delphi, access

Работаю над программой по регистрации данных. На форме имеются компоненты DBEdit откуда вводится и выводится информация с БД(MS Access). Причем информация в поля выводится с запроса в котором производятся некоторые арифметические операции. Т.е все считает БД, а Delphi остается просто вывести эти поля. Но проблема в том что когда я заношу изменения в одно поле, в другом поле с которым это значение связанно, оно не изменяется.  К примеру имеется таблица с полями: [Показатель спидометра на конец] и [Показатель спидометра на начало]. В запросе у меня создается третье поле[Пробег], вычисляемое. 
Пробег: [Показатель спидометра на конец] - [Показатель спидометра на начало]
И соотвественно мы получаем некоторое значение. Все благополучно выводится в дельфи, но если внести изменения в одно из 2-х полей, третье не обнововится.Изменения срабатывают только лишь после закрытия и повторного открытия программы. Как можно реализовать обновление без перезагрузки программы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать

1. Edit mode  - ввести в режим редактирования
2. Post - сохранить изменение после ввода данных
3. ReOpen -- перезапустить Query

Покажите код или компоненты, легче будет объяснить

```
fAutoChange.showmodal;
Connect.TAutomob.Close;
Connect.TAutomob.Open;
```

После закрытия модалного окна закройте (Close) и заново откройте (Open) Таблицу.

Comment: http://rghost.net/7Q7NZkbJ8 код, и компоненты.

Comment: Еще один совет, после `fAutoChange.showmodal;` в кнопке закрытия поставьте  `ModalResult := mrOK;`

Comment: Все получилось! Большое спасибо за помощь!